# Characterization of the Subspace of Quasifree States of the CAR Algebra

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras

Consider $\mathfrak U(\mathfrak H)$, the CAR algebra over a separable Hilbert space $\mathfrak H$. The *states* $E_{\mathfrak U}$ over this algebra are defined to be positive linear functionals of norm one, and the *quasifree states* $E_{\mathfrak U}^0\subseteq E_{\mathfrak U}$ are defined as the even states completely determined by their two-point functions (1)
$$\omega(a^*(f),a(g)),~~~~~\omega(a^*(f)a^*(g))\tag{1}$$
$$\omega(a(f)a^*(f))+\omega(a^*(g)a(g))+\omega(a(f)a(g))+\omega(a(g)a^*(f))\tag{2}$$
and must satisfy the inequality (2). Here, we are using the definition from pp.42-43 of Robinson and Bratelli's [Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics II](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540614432).

My question is: when $\mathfrak H$ is infinite-dimensional, What is the topology/geometry of $E_{\mathfrak U}^0$? Based off of my intuition working in the Fock representation, the infinite-dimensional Spin group should play a significant role in this classification. However, I have trouble applying this intuition to the much more general setting of $C^*$-algebras, where different states may correspond to different representations, and I cannot start with a seed state.

Comment: Have you seen Araki's paper "On Quaslfree States of CAR and
Bogoliubov Automorphisms"? Lemmas 3.2 and 3.3 say that any quasifree state is uniquely determined by a positive contraction $S$ on the Hilbert space satisfying $S + ISI= Id$, where $I$ is the complex conjugation, whose choice is immediate if you start from a real Hilbert space. The operator $S$ is defined as $\omega(a^{\ast}(f) a(g)) = \langle g, Sf\rangle$ if $a^{\ast}(f)$ is the creation operator.